# How should I use token_replace()?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, tokens

Could somebody give me an example of how to use `token_replace()`?
I'm trying to write a custom PHP rule for the Rules module that will rewrite few fields of a new saved content, using the values from tokens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$text = token_replace('token example - [node:title]', array('node' => node_load(123)));
```

Comment: thats really works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

As you are asking about how to replace tokens in a Rules action that is executing custom PHP code, you don't need to replace the tokens with `token_replace()`.

If you enter something similar to the following code, the tokens will be replaced by the Rules module.

```
drupal_set_message(t('This is the node ID: %node-id', array('%node-id' => [node:nid]));
```

The list of the available tokens is reported in the custom PHP action page.

[image: screenshot]